# How to store additional data using GEOADD in redis

Tags: php, redis

I am new to Redis. I need to store multiple location data as below:

```
[
    [
        name: "shop 1", 
        address: "Address1",
        zip: 12345,
        lng: 13.00,
        lat:37.00
    ], [
        name: "shop 2",
        address: "Address2",
        zip: 67890,
        lng: 15.00,
        lat:38.00
    ],
    //…
]
```

I am able to use GEOADD and search using GEORADIUS.
But, GEOADD takes lng, lat and only one parameter. And I need store all othere fields also. And need to search based on address/zip.

Any examples availabe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this in my own app with the following strategy.

Insert the data

```
HSET shop:payload:shop1 name "shop 1" address "address 1" zip 12345
HSET shop:payload:shop2 name "shop 2" address "address 2" zip 67890
GEOADD shop:geo 13.00 37.00 "shop1" 
GEOADD shop:geo 15.00 38.00 "shop2"
```

Query the ids

```
GEORADIUS shop:geo 14.00 38.00 100 mi WITHDIST WITHCOORD
> shop2,54.4615,14.99999910593032837,38.0000009925631943
> shop1,88.2202,12.99999922513961792,37.00000026605963654
```

Query the payloads (I use a pipe in an attempt to speed things up)

```
HGETALL shop:payload:shop2
> {
>   "name": "shop 2",
>   "address": "address 2",
>   "zip": "67890"
> }

HGETALL shop:payload:shop1
> {
>   "name": "shop 1",
>   "address": "address 1",
>   "zip": "12345"
> }
```

Then you join the data on your backend.

```
[
  {
    "name": "shop 2",
    "address": "address 2",
    "zip": "67890",
    "dist": 54.4615,
    "lon": 14.99999910593032837,
    "lat": 38.0000009925631943
  },
  {
    "name": "shop 1",
    "address": "address 1",
    "zip": "12345",
    "dist": 88.2202,
    "lon": 12.99999922513961792,
    "lat": 37.00000026605963654
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks. It works.! But I have to loo through the results. I am also trying the possibility of using Redisearch.

Comment: It seems like Redis is fast enough that doing these types of manual joins is a non-issue.